# Conflicting Objective functions in multi-objective programming problems.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

I have formulated a multi-objective model for supply chain problem. The first two objectives are related to  minimizing the some costs and the third objective function is minimizing the deterioration of the items. A reviewer has asked me that how it is possible that the third objective function has different unit (as the first two are for cost). However, I have studied a lot of research articles that have considered objective functions with different units for their multi-objective problem. Please tell me how can I defend my problem?

Comment: Well presumably you have a parameter in front of each term that scales their importance. The parameter of the last term will have units cost/deterioration. Obviously if you chose to measure deterioration in different units, you would have to change its coefficient accordingly to get the same answer.

Comment: A Pareto optimal solution is still Pareto optimal if different units are used.